# OAuth Redirect URL in (the new) Safari Web Extension

Tags: safari-web-extension

I am porting my chrome extension to Safari. The extension requires the user to sign-in and I use the OAuth code flow, which requires a redirect url.

In Chrome, I can use `chrome.runtime.getURL('/mypage.html')` as a redirect url because in chrome the extension id is never changed.

In Safari, however, the extension id keeps changing in every (xcode) build. This is similar to the behaviour of Firefox but in Firefox, I can use `browser.identity.getRedirectURL()`. Although not reachable, it guarantees to stay the same.

As in Safari, there is NO `browser.identity` and `safari-web-extension://<extension-id>` is blocked by Safari, what url can I use as a redirect URL?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my reply at the apple forum:  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670165?answerId=661186022#661186022

Excerpted from my reply on the Apple Forum:

> As a workaround, you may use whatever reachable URL as an OAuth
> redirect URL and use webRequest.onBeforeRedirect to capture the
> redirect attempt and 'force redirect' e.g. by tabs.update.
>
> Although this will work, it is far from being elegant. It could even
> be error-prone. While Firefox offers a decent solution for this, why
> safari can't / doesn't. This could be a Safari bug or needs a change
> request on Safari.

I haven't heard anything from Apple (as usual).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @RanMarciano. I will update the answer.